# How to calculate several moving averages in R

Tags: r, finance, moving-average

I have 10 years of daily closing prices for the stock: BNS.TO. I want to calculate several moving averages.

If MA *n* = (P *t-1* + P *t-2* + P *t-3* + … + P *t-n*) / n

Where P = the closing prices
and n = number of periods to be averaged

I would need n to be all values ranging from 3 to 200. How should I go about this?

Here is where the data can be downloaded if need be: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BNS.TO/history?p=BNS.TO

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always advisable to post samples of input and expected output in your post with code tags, kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: This is an arima model with order=c(0,0,x) where x runs from 3:200. eg `sapply(3:200,function(x)arima(your_data,order=c(0,0,x))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pracma` package in R. You could have landed on these pages with a simple google search.

Reference: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/movavg

```
if (!require("pracma", character.only=T, quietly=T)) {
  install.packages("pracma")
  library("pracma", character.only=T)
}

MySeries<-1:300 #sample data
df<-data.frame(lapply(3:200, function(x){movavg(MySeries,n=x,"s")}))
names(df)<-paste0("MA",3:200)
```

You can read more about the function on the R documentation page for that package

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMA function from TTR package.

```
library(TTR);
data(ttrc);

# Assume mydata is ttrc    
mydata = ttrc;

# SMA for 5 days - you can also loop thru to vary from 3 days to 200 days
n = paste("day",5,sep="")

# To assign to mydata use !!
mydata = mutate(mydata,!!n := SMA(Close,5) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MA <- sample(30:70, 2500, T)

library(zoo)
rollingmeans <- lapply(3:200, function(x) {rollmean(MA, x)})
```

This generates a list with rolling means of widths 3 until widths of 200.